# range partition table with a modified column value without recreating the table

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a column of "timestamp" in my table with type of `bigint(20)`. However the value inserted there is a multiplication of unix timestamp resulting with additional digits. Example is following:

Inserted is *153182595270039* which is actually *1531825952* (17 July 2018)

The table has the following value as an example:

```
uid | car_name | ts
1   | redcar    | 153182595270039
```

I want to do a partition based on the above timestamp using range.

However this does not seems straight forward due to the above value is not a unix timestamp accepted by `PARTITION BY RANGE`.

To workaround this issue I have created an additional column with a manipulation of the `ts` column, and later on partition on the newly created column:

```
1. create a temporary column of "partition_category"
ALTER TABLE car_table ADD partition_category bigint(20);
2. copy the ts into partition_category/100000 
UPDATE car_table SET partition_category=ts/100000;
3. Execute the partition
ALTER TABLE car_table PARTITION BY RANGE (partition_category) ( PARTITION p201701 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2018-02-01 00:00:00")), PARTITION p201707 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2018-07-01 00:00:00")));
```

However the above steps failed because of *A `PRIMARY KEY` must include all columns in the table's partitioning function* which means I have to rebuild the table on the `CREATE` step to consider the newly introduced `partition_category`

Are there any better ways to do partition of `ts` if the given value is as above? Is it possible to do a partition without having to change the `CREATE` table statement?

Comment: Can't you just define the ranges not as dates, but in the same form you use for `ts` (so a unix timestamp multiplied by 100000)?

Comment: @Solarflare I dont have any hard requirement apart of using the range partitioning, but I don't really get what you are referring to? is it like PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) * 100000 ) ?

Comment: I meant something like `PARTITION BY RANGE (ts) ( PARTITION p201701 VALUES LESS THAN (153182595200000), ...`, so instead of translating your `ts` to some date, you translate the date (that you want to describe the ranges) to your form of `ts`.

Comment: @Solarflare that is also possible, but I want to know if I can work first with ts as unix timestamp that is easily understood by the function caller and not with the above form where additional ts manipulation will be done later after the partition.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. The function caller has no (or doesn't need) knowledge of the format you used to define the ranges (you can btw use `LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00:00')*100000)` too). He sees and uses the value `ts`. If he doesn't like that value, you can add your additional column (e.g. as a generated column), but that could be independent from partitioning. If the user doesn't use `ts` in his queries, partitioning will likely slow them down a bit, but keep in mind that partitioning isn't supposed to speed up queries.